# Slow SDE Feature Class Performance

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, spatial-database, performance, feature-class

I've been experiencing slower than usual performance (noticeably slow time to draw as well as query, compared to similar feature classes) with a specific feature class in my organizations enterprise geodatabase.  The feature class consists of tax parcel polygons in the Local Government schema (vector_data.DBO.ParcelPublishing/vector_data.DBO.TaxParcel).  It is a non-versioned feature class with archiving enabled.

I've tried the following to speed it up (with no success):

- We reconcile, post, and compress our GDB nightly
- Feature class has an attribute index as well as a spatial index
- I have run "rebuild indexes" as well as "analyze datasets" on the feature class with just about every combination of options possible

Any suggestions as to what I should try next?

Our enterprise geodatabase is on version 10.3 on top of SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Lots of detail missing here.  Please edit the question to specify the release and service pack of SQL Server 2008, the geometry storage type (SDEBINARY or GEOMETRY or GEOGRAPHY) the exact number  of features, and the exact times for specific tasks in seconds or milliseconds.